# how to get Origin of image from sprite?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am using cocos2dx c++ and I am getting width of Picture inside Sprite with

```
playerSprite->getTextureRect().origin.x;
playerSprite->getTextureRect().origin.y;
```

Like Width of Sprite is 400 and Width of Picture is 140 .
But I want to get X and Y point of Origin of Picture not Sprite . Can Anyone Please Help me.

Picture Link:https://www.dropbox.com/s/kl9eye2gs1onwsq/s1.png?dl=0

Comment: you have 1 Sprite & you having a picture on it ??  i mean you have added any other image on your sprite ?   actually i am not getting your question..  like i can see your s1.png  , in which you have some image which having black background , right .. so you want origin of that person picture inside this image which is having black background ?

Comment: yes, I need origin of person not the image with black background.

Comment: you are looking for playerSprite->position or that position minus contentSize multiplied with anchorPoint for the lower left corner of the sprite texture

Comment: as far as i know , you cant have exact origin position of some image inside  your Sprite . there is no way doing this in cocos as per my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used

```
playerSprite->getSpriteFrame()->getOffsetInPixels().x;
playerSprite->getSpriteFrame()->getOffsetInPixels().y;
```

to get origin

Answer (score -1):

Try to use getContentSize() instead of getTextureRect()